# Assemble mpeg file unable to play in mediaplayer

Tags: python, video, mpeg

I'm currently working on a school project and i seem to encouter some problems with an MPEG file. The scope of my project is to:

1) split MPEG file into many fixed size chunk.

2) assemble some of them while omitting certain chunk.

---

**Problem 1:**

When i play the file in media player, it will play the video until it reaches the chunk that i omit.

Example:

```
chunk = ["yui_1", "yui_2", "yui_3", "yui_5", "yui_6"]
Duration of each chunk: 1 second
```

*If you realise i have omitted "yui_4" chunk.*

If I were to assemble all the chunk except "yui_4", the video will play first 2 seconds before it hangs throughout the duration.

---

**Problem 2:**

When i assemble the chunk while omitting the first chunk, it render the entire mpeg file unable to play.

Example:

```
chunk = ["yui_2", "yui_3", "yui_4", "yui_5", "yui_6"]
Duration of each chunk: 1 second
```

---

### Below is a portion of my code (hardcode):

```
def splitFile(inputFile,chunkSize):

    splittext = string.split(filename, ".")
    name = splittext[0]
    extension = splittext[1]

    os.chdir("./" + media_dir)

    #read the contents of the file
    f = open(inputFile, 'rb')
    data = f.read() # read the entire content of the file
    f.close()

    # get the length of data, ie size of the input file in bytes
    bytes = len(data)

    #calculate the number of chunks to be created
    noOfChunks= bytes/chunkSize
    if(bytes%chunkSize):
            noOfChunks+=1

    #create a info.txt file for writing metadata
    f = open('info.txt', 'w')
    f.write(inputFile+','+'chunk,'+str(noOfChunks)+','+str(chunkSize))
    f.close()

    chunkNames = []
    count = 1
    for i in range(0, bytes+1, chunkSize):
            fn1 = name + "_%s" % count
            chunkNames.append(fn1)
            f = open(fn1, 'wb')
            f.write(data[i:i+ chunkSize])
            count += 1
            f.close()
```

---

### Below is a portion of how i assemble the chunk:

```
def assemble():

    data = ["yui_1", "yui_2", "yui_3", "yui_4", "yui_5", "yui_6", "yui_7"]
    output = open("output.mpeg", "wb")
    for item in datafile:
            data = open(item, "rb"). read()
            output.write(data)
    output.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

MPEG video files contain "encoded video data" which means it is compressed. The bottom line is that cutting up the video into chunks that can be appended or played separately is not trivial. Both your problems will not be solved unless you read the MPEG2 transport stream specification carefully and understand where to find points which you can cut and "splice" and still output a compliant MPEG stream. My guess is that this isn't what you want to do for a school project.

Maybe you should try to read how to use FFMPEG (http://www.ffmpeg.org/) to cut and append video files.

Good luck on your project.